# Image as checkbox in Angular

Tags: image, angularjs, checkbox, input

I'm going to implement an element in Angular which would be able to set a value to a hidden field and change a state of the element on mouse click. Shortly, I need an image which behaves like a checkbox. To implement this element I decided to make a Angular "directive". But when I change the value of the container selection state, the 'selected' class is not added to the container. How to do this in right way with Angular?

Also I can't figure out how to update the input's value, what technique to choose here. Note, that initial state of the hidden field goes from a server side.

This is a demo of the problem: [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/QgCiSt3YCgAvmEI45FfP).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HOo2tA8PmcZf7jJvLv9z?p=preview). There were three small errors:

1. Your CSS class for `.selected` was missing the `solid` attribute for the border.
2. You need to call `$apply` in your directives click listener to update the scope:

   ```
   el.on('click', function() {
     scope.isSelected = !scope.isSelected;
     scope.$apply();
   });
   ```
3. You used ng-class in the wrong order:

   ```
   ng-class="{selected: isSelected}"
   ```